# Вставить картинку в Label

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь вставить в `Label` картинку, но выдает ошибку `Image "..." does not exist`, путь **точно** верный.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

img = PhotoImage("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg")

b = Label(image = img)
b.img = "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg"
b.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Искал, да так и не нашел, в чем проблема. Пробовал писать `im = Image.open(path_to_file)` и соответственно `img = PhotoImage(im)`, но выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Измените `PhotoImage(...)` на `PhotoImage(file=...)`

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter` не поддерживает `jpeg`. Можно сделать так:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

tk = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg"))

b = Label(image = img)

b.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

`pil` поддерживает очень много форматов